# Split the [manual] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[manual](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/manual) usage is evenly divided between people referring to documentation and people referring to doing things by hand.  Recommend splitting it into two tags that each have a consistent meaning. [documentation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/documentation) already exists and is probably a good one for one meaning.  Something like [manual-procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/manual-procedure) would be clearer for the other.

Comment: Manual procedure does not require a tag

Comment: Agreed. Remove the [manual]-by-hand uses, and synonymize into [documentation]